# Why will this return distance between addresses in the same city but wont if the addresses are in different cities

Tags: json, excel, vba

So I have an excel VBA module that will get the distance between addresses using google maps. It works if the addresses are in the same city but will not work if the address is in different cities.

```
Function TRAVELDISTANCE(origin, destination, apikey)
 
    Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & origin & "&destination=" & destination & "&key=" & apikey
     
    Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With httpReq
         .Open "GET", strUrl, False
         .Send
    End With
     
    Dim response As String
    response = httpReq.ResponseText
     
    Dim parsed As Dictionary
    Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
    Dim meters As Integer
     
    Dim leg As Dictionary
     
     
    For Each leg In parsed("routes")(1)("legs")
        meters = meters + leg("distance")("value")
    Next leg
     
     
     
    TRAVELDISTANCE = meters
 
End Function
```

This module works for time between address in different cities and states and they are basically the same code.
Function TRAVELTIME(origin, destination, apikey)

```
Dim strUrl As String
strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & origin & "&destination=" & destination & "&key=" & apikey
 
Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
With httpReq
     .Open "GET", strUrl, False
     .Send
End With
 
Dim response As String
response = httpReq.ResponseText
 
Dim parsed As Dictionary
Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
Dim seconds As Integer
 
Dim leg As Dictionary
 
For Each leg In parsed("routes")(1)("legs")
    seconds = seconds + leg("duration")("value")
Next leg
 
 
 
TRAVELTIME = seconds
```

End Function

Comment: Likely an issue with your formatting of origin or destination

Comment: The formatting works for the time between addresses module

Comment: I can't test the `directions` api. But for the `distancematrix` api, improperly formatted addresses don't work for either distance or time. I have nothing else to offer, and, obviously, I cannot see the argument `strURL` you are actually sending.

Comment: If you require more assistance, I suggest you provide sufficient information that someone can reproduce your problem.